# Is it possible to solve problem 4 (double integral) without using a graphing calculator?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

[image]

I know how to solve problem 4 but I cheated by using the Wolfram Alpha graphing calculator. Is there any way to solve it without a calculator?

Comment: Graphing polar equations is a standard mathematical technique; see [here](http://www.analyzemath.com/polarcoordinates/graphing_polar_equations.html) for a tutorial.  None of these four examples are particularly unusual, and can be done by hand.

Answer (score 1):

One petal means that $\theta$ has a range such that $r=0$ at both ends only. That means $0<\theta<\pi/4$. Actually, we can split the petal in half and say that $0<\theta<\pi/4$. When doing areas, the density is always equal to 1 in rectangular form, but since we are in polar coordinates, we have the find the jacobian which is $r$, so we have $\int_0^{\pi/8}\int_0^{8\sin 4\theta}rdrd\theta$. That should get you started.